# Sorted insert program in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am a beginner in Data structures and I am learning linked list now .
I encountered a program about sorted insert where I had an add() function to add the nodes in the sorted order

```
         /*Linked List program to add ascending order sorted nodes in     

         the list */
 #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
enter code here
 struct node {
   int data ;
   struct node link;

 };

 void add(struct node **q,int num){
    struct node *r,*temp = *q;
    r = malloc(sizeof(struct node )); //Data Allocated
    r->data = num;

    if(*q==NULL ||(*q)->data >num){
     *q = r;
     (*q)->link = temp;

    }else{
      while(temp !=NULL){
         if(temp->data <=num &&(temp->link->data >num                    
                                             ||temp->link==NULL)){
             r->link = temp->link;
             temp->link=r;
             return;
         }
          temp = temp->link;
      }

    }

 }

 void main(){
 struct node *p;
 p = NULL;

 }
```

I have expected to add the nodes in sorted ascending order but when I input data then error is shown.I am Using Code Blocks to run the program in C

I think it has to do something with the end condition temp->link == null but I am unable to figure out exact condition for that part of code .Please Help !

Comment: *'run the program in C'* – then why C++ tag?

Comment: You are checking for `temp !=NULL` but you are accessing `temp->link`. `temp->link` can be `NULL` in which case you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: Also the structure definition is wrong. Maybe you wanted. `struct node *link;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The definition for the structure `struct node` is not correct. I assume it is a typo. It should be `struct node *link;`
2. Your conditions for traversing the loop are not correct.  As mentioned in the comments, you are accessing `temp->link` in case it might be `NULL`.
3. You are not checking for the condition that the number to be added is greater than all the numbers and is to be added at the end of the list.

The modified function is below.

```
 void add(struct node **q,int num){
    struct node *r,*temp = *q;
    r = malloc(sizeof(struct node )); //Data Allocated
    r->data = num;
    r->link = NULL;

    if(*q==NULL ||(*q)->data >num){
     *q = r;
     (*q)->link = temp;

    }else{
      while(temp->link !=NULL){
         if(temp->data <=num &&(temp->link->data >num)){
             r->link = temp->link;
             temp->link=r;
             return;
         }
         temp = temp->link;
      }
      temp ->link = r; // add at the end as not added at any other location.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! But besides Any typing error I wanted to know the exact logic where I can specify the numbers at the end of the linked list where temp->link is null and A larger number has to inserted at the end of the list

Comment: As you can see there is no explicit condition for that

Comment: In the code above, if you exit the while loop you are at the end of the list and the number is greater than all the numbers in the list.  It is added at the end by `temp ->link = r;`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Rishikesh Raje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3555525/rishikesh-raje)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58129929/1312382) (you need to use a pointer inside struct: `struct node* link;`; you need to check *first* for `link` being null, then access `link->data`), the loop can be simplified quite a bit:

```
// advance only, if we need to insert (at least) after temp->link:
while(temp->link && temp->link->data <= num)
{
    temp = temp->link;
}
// once the loop is done, temp points to the last element smaller than num, so:
r->link = temp->link;
temp->link = r;
```

Inside the while, we don't need to check for `temp->data > num`; we re-enter the loop only, if the loop condition was met previously, which checked exactly this condition already; remains the very first loop run; however, in this case, your `if` before the loop covered the condition already.

Side note: Is it a requirement to insert new elements *after* the existing ones? If not, inserting *in front of* is a bit faster, all you'd do is replacing `<=` with `<` and `>` with `>=`...

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
( temp->link == NULL || temp->link->data > num )
```

instead of

```
( temp->link->data > num || temp->link == NULL )
```

because if temp->link is NULL, the first code will return true immediately after checking the first condition and will not check the second condition, thus you will not get an error. 
But when you use it like in the second expression, if temp->link is NULL, you will get an error because you are trying to reach a field named "data" of a NULL object with the code

```
temp->link->data
```